# CSS - Moving items around in Navbar

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

See screenshots for what I am trying to achieve.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/fFBQh.jpg

https://i.stack.imgur.com/DAEJM.jpg

The menu list items (My application, Register, Login) I want to move to the far right of the screen. I have tried messing with the margins, float:right, however still cannot get this to work.

The container div spans the full width. Would I need to amend this div?

I've created a codeped to illustrate this

https://codepen.io/jquerypain121/pen/OJNaWpa

```
<html><head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Log in - PhotoUploaderForm</title>

</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-toggleable-sm navbar-dark bg-white border-bottom box-shadow mb-3">
            <div class="container">
                <img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/proxy/HQAE10KQ0NmS9htB5BKSoN24jWvyaizAKwhGy8hNVVsCbFUubvDdLSsYB8xWbN3JUDzDuAzw0OxKO5QZyL_XPqitq1wcSYaMVJ35_oC48c4FKZYykJUoucS-LJT1" width="200" title="title" alt="additional title">

                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">My Application</a>

                <div class="navbar-collapse collapse d-sm-inline-flex flex-sm-row-reverse">

                    <ul class=" moveright nav navbar-nav">
                            <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">My Application</a>
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link text-dark" id="register" href="/Identity/Account/Register">Register</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link text-dark" id="login" href="/Identity/Account/Login">Login</a>
                            </li>
                    </ul>

                    <ul class="navbar-nav flex-grow-1">
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </header>

    <div class="container-fluid">
        


        <main role="main" class="pb-3">
            


<h1>Log in</h1>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <section>
            <form id="account" method="post" action="/Identity/Account/Login" novalidate="novalidate">    
                <hr>
                <div class="text-danger validation-summary-valid" data-valmsg-summary="true"><ul><li style="display:none"></li>
</ul></div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="Input_Email">Email</label>
                    <input class="form-control" type="email" data-val="true" data-val-email="The Email field is not a valid e-mail address." data-val-required="The Email field is required." id="Input_Email" name="Input.Email" value="">
                    <span class="text-danger field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="Input.Email" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="Input_Password">Password</label>
                    <input class="form-control" type="password" data-val="true" data-val-required="The Password field is required." id="Input_Password" name="Input.Password">
                    <span class="text-danger field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="Input.Password" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="checkbox">
                        <label for="Input_RememberMe">
                            <input type="checkbox" data-val="true" data-val-required="The Remember me? field is required." id="Input_RememberMe" name="Input.RememberMe" value="true">
                            Remember me?
                        </label>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" formaction="/Identity/Account/Login?returnUrl=%2F">Log in</button>
                    <input type="hidden" id="ReturnUrl" name="ReturnUrl" value="/">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    
                    <p>
                        <a href="/Identity/Account/Register?returnUrl=%2F">Register as a new user</a>
                    </p>
                    
                </div>

            <input name="__RequestVerificationToken" type="hidden" value="CfDJ8PEcG7qoomVJk-wiZaqy0p6b5tfvXZTuVH-9YakoOKQQf8mWfBn4MYD7BCb3YKL_NmEz_Ru57zD8PV8Tq_6ea5WApccwrpwYrOkBdu7Qu9Z6NMycGCHqDTI35Ci1mPMVQSqyQ47sNdvfhZhfkMSx_DQ"><input name="Input.RememberMe" type="hidden" value="false"></form>

        </section>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-2">

    </div>
</div>


        </main>
    </div>
    <footer class="border-top footer text-muted">
        <div class="container">
            <p style="float:left;color: white;">© 2020 - Leicestershire Health Informatics Service -</p>
            <a style="float:right; margin-right: 10px;" href="/Home/Privacy">Privacy</a>
            <a style="float:right;margin-right: 10px;" href="/Home/Information">Info</a>
            <a style="float:right;margin-right: 10px;" href="/Home/TermsAndConditions">T&amp;C</a>
        </div>
    </footer>







</body></html>
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks

Comment: Those items moved to the right perfectly. you used container class just after nav. That's why those items are on the right side according to width. if you remove container class those items will be aligned to right side.

Comment: If I remove the container class, those menu items switch to the far left, and wrap underneath near to the image logo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you don't need to customize the code. Bootstrap has it's own design which you want to achieve. For your reference https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/components/navbar/

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<nav class="navbar navbar-light bg-light">
  <a class="navbar-brand">
   <img src="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/assets/brand/bootstrap-solid.svg" width="30" height="30" class="d-inline-block align-top">
  My Application
  </a>
  <div class="form-inline">
    <a class="nav-link text-dark" href="">My Application</a>
    <a class="nav-link text-dark" id="register" href="/Identity/Account/Register">Register</a>
    <a class="nav-link text-dark" id="login" href="/Identity/Account/Login">Login</a>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of writing moveright in your ul class list, write ml-auto. This should move the list to the right.

Comment: That still didn't work unfortunately. The div that this ul element is in, is not taking up the full width of the container. I tried with 100% on this div but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Make the width of the nav 100%
and then make the ul float: right;

Hope it will work for you